# !== not comparing strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare two string using below code

```
var roomStatus = $("#room-status").val().trim();
var inService = "In Service";
var caInService = "CA In Service";

if (roomStatus !== inService || roomStatus !== caInService) 
{
  swal({
      title: "Allotment Cancelled",
      type: "error",
      text: "The Student cannot be alloted to this Room because this room is "+roomStatus,
  });
  return false;
}
```

The above code is not comparing if roomStatus equals In Service. It always falls in if condition.
Please help !!!

Comment: Have you checked what roomStatus is returning and its type? Also it looks like you are looking to check if any of both strings match in order to raise the notice.

Comment: yes it is fetching i m debugging the code

Comment: It's because you're using an OR condition. You need to invert your logic.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: actually i am checking if room status contains out of service or ca out of service, then it should raise an issue

Comment: try this var roomStatus = $("#room-status").val().trim().toString();

Comment: in this code, no matter what you have in your roomservice, it will end up true.. If it is the one, it is not the other, if it is the other, it is not the one. no matter what you write, it will either not be `inService` or it will not be `caInService` - your logic is flawed

Comment: What exactly is the value of `roomStatus`? [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298772/not-comparing-strings#comment93478447_53298772) seems to very much muddy the waters

Comment: logic explanation : you check if it is NOT and apple, OR it is NOT a pear - everything in the world falls into this logic. - even pears and apples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an algorithm, there are two conditions groups that are pointless (with `if (true)` and `if (false)`) :

```
if (var !== val1 || var !== val2)
```

will always evaluate to `true` : if `var` is equal to `val1`, it's not equal to `val2`, and vice-versa.

```
if (var === val1 && var === val2)
```

will always evaluate to false, because `var` can't have two values at the same time.

> **note:** Here I consider `val1 !== val2` and simple conditions with no affectation

Answer (score 3):

replace this line:

```
if (roomStatus !== inService || roomStatus !== caInService) {
```

with

```
if (!(roomStatus === inService || roomStatus === caInService)) {
```

## Edit

as suggested by commenters, this line would be a lot easier to read:

```
if (roomStatus !== inService && roomStatus !== caInService) {
```

Comment: `if (roomStatus !== inService && roomStatus !== caInService)` is nicer, I think... (But that's a personal opinion, nothing objective)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer is right. I don't think it's personal preference either, the logic in this answer is just confusing